# ¿Por que mi base de datos H2 esta vacia despues de ejecutar JUnit test correctamente?

Tags: java, h2

Incorpore la base de datos H2 para poder realizar los Junit Test. Cuando ejecuta la aplicacion las tablas se crean correctamente, y cuando realizo los test no contienen fallas ni errores pero las tablas siguen vacias. Este es el codigo que estoy ejecutando. Tambien agregue el archivo data.sql

Esta es mi clase test:

```
@Profile("test")
public class UsuarioRepoTest {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepo usuarioRepo;

    @Test
    public void crearUsuarioTest() {
        Usuario usuarioTest = usuarioRepo.save(new Usuario("test", "testPrueba", "test@prueba.com", "1234"));
        Usuario usuarioEncontrado = usuarioRepo.findById(usuarioTest.getIdUsuario()).get();

        assertNotNull(usuarioEncontrado);
        assertEquals(usuarioTest.getIdUsuario(), usuarioEncontrado.getIdUsuario());
    }
```

Este es mi aplication.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

en el aplication.properties por default tambien configure el perfil test:

`spring.profiles.active=test`

Este es mi repositorio:

```
public interface UsuarioRepo extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Integer> {

     Optional<Usuario> findByNombre(String nombre);
     
     Optional<Usuario> findByNombreUsuario(String nombreUsuario);
     
     boolean existsByNombre(String nombre);
     
     boolean existsByEmail(String email);

     boolean existsById(Integer id);

    boolean existsByNombreUsuario(String nombreUsuario);
     }
```

Y esta es mi entidad

```
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idUsuario;
    private String nombre;
    private String nombreUsuario;
    private String email;
    private String contrasena;

    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idUsuario", nullable = false), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idRol", nullable = false))
    private Set<Role> rol = new HashSet<>();;

    public Usuario() {

    }

    public Usuario(String nombre, String nombreUsuario, String email, String contrasena) {

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.nombreUsuario = nombreUsuario;
        this.email = email;
        this.contrasena = contrasena;

    }
// getters y setters
```

Y esta es mi consola H2 :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No muestras tu configuración de Spring ni tu repositorio, pero lo que intuyo está pasando, es que cuando Spring maneja los tests, al terminar la transacción se hace automáticamente un roll-back para volver todo al estado antes de ejecutar el test. Por lo tanto si tus tablas estaban vacías antes de comenzar el test, seguirán vacías después del test.

Este es el comportamiento deseado, ya que los tests no deben cambiar el estado anterior de nada, porque si no podrían influir en el resultado del próximo test. Y recuerda que no hay garantía del orden en que se ejecutan los tests.